# How to manipulate two different models in a single view with ASP.NET MVC? (Likert Scale Case)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, radio-button

I'm trying to create a Likert scale. For those who might not know the term, probably you have seen one of these before. There are multiple options to pick (7 in my case) which shows how much you agree or disagree with given idea or situation. I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6

I use radio buttons for my option selection part.

I don't want to show all my 36 questions at a time. Therefore I send 6 question objects for each request, 6 questions will be displayed in the view. In order to achieve that, an id parameter is passed to achieve pagination and here's how I respond:

```
public ActionResult List(int id = 1)
        {
        int PageNo = 6 * (id - 1);
        MyDBEntities ctx = new MyDBEntities();
        IEnumerable<question> QuestionsToBeSent = new List<question>();

        QuestionsToBeSent = from q in ctx.questions
                            where (q.QuestionNo > PageNo) && 
                           (q.QuestionNo <= (id* 6))  select q;
            ViewBag.PageNo = id;
            return View(QuestionsToBeSent);
        }
```

and I can show the question sentences properly in the view. The problem is when I want to save selected options for 6 questions displayed, I cannot access answer model in the view since I already included the question model. Another problem is I send my request via Html.Actionlink() and what I pass is only a number to proceed in pagination

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next Page", "List", "Question", new {id = ViewBag.PageNo+1},null)
```

Last of my problems is about sending this request and its content. I am not able to collect responses from radio buttons. If I could collect, I believe I can send another piece of data in the type of answer object and then I can write an overload for my List action in QuestionController that accets a secondary answer type. If I can understand how to get responses from radio buttons and how to manipulate a secondary model in a single view, I guess I can handle the rest. I can catch and insert the answers in the overload List() method.

I create the radio buttons for questions as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<p class="lead">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionSentence)</p>
<label> I Agree </label>
   <input type="radio" value=3 name="DontKnowWhattoName">
   <input type="radio" value=2 name="DontKnowWhattoName">
   <input type="radio" value=1 name="DontKnowWhattoName">
   <input type="radio" value=0 name="DontKnowWhattoName">
   <input type="radio" value=-1 name="DontKnowWhattoName">
   <input type="radio" value=-2 name="DontKnowWhattoName">
   <input type="radio" value=-3 name="DontKnowWhattoName">
<label> I Disagree </label>

}
```

Since the radio controls are created dynamically and I have 7 for each question, I'm really troubled on how to detect the selected one, how to name and access it and then how to properyl pass it to the controller?

Sorry for such a long question but I really could not break it into seperate parts as I believe all of those are quite interwined.

Comment: Use a view model class that contains the question and the 6 possible answers. Don't use the `question` class itself.

Comment: And use `.Skip()` and `.Take()` for paging data

Comment: Thanks a lot both Gert and Stephen. I managed to achieve the pagination using .Skip() and .Take(). However, I'm still troubled with radio buttons although I'm glad for realizing ViewModel approach.